# Webpage limitations when wrapped inside an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am developing a webpage which our customers want to insert on their websites by wrapping my page in an `iframe` (*cross domain*). I **don't** need to interact with the parent or know anything about whats outside the *iframe*.

I am using *HTML*, *CSS*, *Javascript* and *Webservices*.

**Question:** How am I limited inside an *iframe* compared to if my page was running outside the *iframe*?

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly what the limitations are, but if your iframe content does not need to access the parent page, you woul dnot encounter any of them. I suppose this question is purely an intellectual pursuit? :)

Comment: Searching for related answers gives me a lot of very specific solutions to various *iframe* problems. I am searching for a more general *don't do this*, *don't do that* and be aware that *this is not possible* when residing in an *iframe*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not. Any JS linked within the iframe from your domain will act in the context of the iframe. Aside from being crammed into an unusual container it should work the same as it would if it was loaded independently.

If your needs should change however, there are ways to send signals between parent frame and iframe if both pages have JS written to cooperate. There's methods using the # in URLs which can be read by the parent and don't force page reloads and I believe they share the window.resize event which can be fired manually without actually resizing the window.

UPDATE: There are far better ways to communicate between cross-domain iframes now than there used to be. Naturally you'll still require cooperating JS on both ends but you can use `window.postMessage` rather than triggering messages via window.resize and data after a hash symbol in the URL. That was a cool trick though.

Comment: **@Erik**: Thanks for your answer. But what about moving on to another *url* (not moving away from the iframe) using `<a/>`, the javascript *window.location...* and so on?

Comment: Every frame gets its own window object. The idea is to be able to throw any src in that you want and view it and use it in the iframe, unless of course they have frame busting code built in. If JS within the iframe defines a global variable, it will be a property of that iframe's window object. The parent window can access the .src element of the child iframe and I believe they both see the same window.resize since that's more of a chrome event but other than that it's like two separate pages in every way as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

When creating links you should have in mind to maybe use the `target`-attribute of the `a`-tag if you want to create a link for the parent window. Otherwise the new page would be loaded into the iframe.